# Software for Data Management

Tags: database, data-visualization, data-analysis, data, server

I'm looking for software that can review all data inside of a server and its database.

The result of this software can help you to review how many pictures, installed software and other files that take a lot of space.

You are also able to review what kind of data that each user stores etc.

The purpose is to know what kind of data that is being stored inside of this server and how much space it takes? Too much space cost too much money.

Do you know of any software?

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: Any tutorial for OS?

Comment: On windows, use the search and search for all image extentions, then for installed software it takes 2 min to count them in the `Programs and Features`. as for the files that take lots of space, again windows search allow you to search for such file using the `Size:Huge` or `Size:Gigantic`, there is a drop down for that you have like 8 choices

Comment: @Franck and if it's Linux or Mac? After all, OP asks for a server, so that might very well be a Linux machine. // ***HelloWorld:*** This is not the place to ask for tutorials. And without knowing what OS your machine runs on (you should know that), suggestions for a matching software are hard. Please see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your question accordingly :) A bit more precision cannot hurt either, it's quite vague: you want to look inside files, or just "count by type"?

Comment: In my context, it would be Microsoft and Unix.